# Hacer consulta mysql con sumatoria

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un tabla en la que guardo las líneas de las facturas emitidas y, entre otros, tienen los siguientes datos:

-id_articulo
-id_cliente
-unidades

Pues bien quiero hacer una consulta para saber los artículos más vendidos a cada cliente y la cantidad de artículos vendidos. Para ello necesito listar esta tabla agrupada por artículo y saber la cantidad vendida de cada uno. El problema es que yo he conseguido que me muestre de cada artículo el número total de lineas, pero lo que yo quiero que me muestre es la suma del número total de unidades.

```
<?php 

//Esta consulta sirve pero me devuelve el número de lineas en que aparece cada artículo y yo quiero saber la suma de las unidades de ese artículo 

$articulo_mas_ventas = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_articulo, COUNT(*) NumeroVentas  FROM tt_facturas_lineas WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente' GROUP BY id_articulo ORDER BY NumeroVentas DESC ");

echo '<table class="table table-centered table-nowrap table-hover mb-0">';

foreach ($articulo_mas_ventas as $key => $valuecli) {

     $NumeroVentas = $valuecli["NumeroVentas"];

     $id_articulo = $valuecli['id_articulo'];

    $consulta_articulo = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tt_articulos WHERE id = '$id_articulo'");

    $datos_articulo = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_articulo);


     echo '
            
            <tr>
                
                <td>
                    
                    <h6 class="font-14 my-1 fw-normal"><strong>'.$datos_articulo["referencia"].' </strong></h6>

                    <span class="text-muted font-13">Referencia</span>
                
                </td>

                <td>
                    
                    <h6 class="font-14 my-1 fw-normal"><strong>'.$datos_articulo["nombre"].' </strong></h6>

                    <span class="text-muted font-13">Nombre</span>
                
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                
                <td>
                    
                    <h5 class="font-14 my-1 fw-normal"><strong>'.$NumeroVentas.' </strong></h5>
                    
                    <span class="text-muted font-13">Número de ventas</span>
                
                </td>
                
                <td>
                   
                </td>
            
            </tr>

        
        ';

}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Vale, al final lo he logrado, por si alguien lo necesita así funciona:

```
$articulo_mas_ventas = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id_articulo, COUNT(*) NumeroVentas, SUM(unidades) CantidadVendida  FROM tt_facturas_lineas WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente' GROUP BY id_articulo ORDER BY NumeroVentas DESC ");
```